# Transparently mount a tar.gz archive with Python

Tags: python, archive, tar, fuse

**How can I mount a tar.gz archive transparently with Python?**

I have a tar.gz archive whose contents have to be read by an external program. The contents will only be needed temporarily. I could just unpack it to a temporary folder and point my external program there to read it. Afterwards, I could just delete the temp folder again. However, the archives may be large (>1 GB when extracted) so that unpacking them will take up a lot of space on the disk. My server is rather weak regarding HD performance and I cannot waste space ad lib but it does have a lot of RAM and CPU power.

That's why I want to try to mount the archive transparently without unpacking it entirely. I came across [archivemount](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-mounts-an-archive-for-access-as-a-file-system) which seems to do exactly what I want. **Is there a way to do what archivemount does in pure Python?** No subprocess.call "solutions", please. It should run on 64-bit Linux.

I believe there should be a smart way to use [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) to access archive's contents   and then [fusepy](https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy) to create a user-space file system which exposes the contents of the archive. Has anyone already put these pieces together? Any ideas?

If you think that this is not a good idea, please post relevant comments. If you know what is better, please comment.

Comment: I would think using archivemount is the easiest way to go. it is readily available in various distributions, and you only need 1 command to mount your archive. fusepy has not been touched in 2 years. Depending on your precise needs, `tarfile` on its own can be sufficient, too.

Comment: You mention using `tarfile` *after* exposing the contents. Is this a tar inside of a tar?

Comment: @DanGetz Good point, I edited the question to make it clearer. I want to use `tarfile` first to access the archive and then `fusepy` to create the file system.

Comment: Are you certain that reading files into memory with `TarFile.extractfile()` isn't enough for what you're doing?

Comment: @DanGetz Yes quite sure. The contents have to be read by an external program which expects the contents of the archive as if they were extracted on the file system (including folder hierarchy). I do not control the reader module and hence can't simply add support to read archives. And I don't know in advance which files it will open so I need to give it everything.

Comment: In modern Linux, the /tmp is often stored in memory (often half the RAM). A second possibility would be /dev/shm. You should read about "tmpfs".

Answer (score 2):

As of version 0.3.1 of my [ratarmount](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount) module, you can use it or take a look at its source to mount a .tar.gz in Python. The gzip seeking support is from the dependency [indexed_gzip](https://github.com/pauldmccarthy/indexed_gzip). Ratarmount itself is based on [tarindexer](https://github.com/devsnd/tarindexer), which implements the idea to use tarfile to get offsets and then seek to it. But, ratarmount adds a FUSE layer among other usability and performance features.

You can install ratarmount from PyPI:

```
pip3 install --user ratarmount
```

and then call its command line interface directly from python like so:

```
import ratarmount
ratarmount.cli( [ '--help' ] )
ratarmount.cli( [ pathToTar, pathToMountPoint ] )
```

The heart of the module is as you already surmised [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html), which is used to iterate over all TarInfo objects and create a list of filepath,offset,size, which then can be used to seek directly to the offset in the raw tar file and the simply read the next size bytes. This works because TAR is that simple of a format.

Here is the unoptimized and very bare core idea:

```
import sys
import tarfile
from indexed_gzip import IndexedGzipFile

targzfile = sys.argv[1]
filetoprint = sys.argv[2]

index = {} # path : ( offset, size )

file = IndexedGzipFile( targzfile )
for tarinfo in tarfile.open( fileobj = file, mode = 'r|' ):
    index[tarinfo.name] = ( tarinfo.offset_data, tarinfo.size )

# at this point you could save or load the index for faster consecutive file seeks

file.seek( index[filetoprint][0] )
sys.stdout.buffer.write( file.read( index[filetoprint][1] ) )
```

The above example was tested to work with:

```sh
wget -O- 'https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/70.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-70.0.tar.bz2' | bzip2 -d -c | gzip > firefox.tgz
python3 minimal-example.py firefox.tgz firefox/updater.ini
```